# ansible use of wild card in with_items and loop

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

Team,

Using single full defined string in `with_item` I have my task running fine. However, at scale i would like to loop with string inside with_items changing. any hints?

```
      - name: "Fetch all CPU nodes from clusters using K8s beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type"
        k8s_facts:
          kind: Node
          label_selectors:
          - "beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=e1.xlarge"

          verify_ssl: no
        register: cpu_class_list
        failed_when: cpu_class_list == ''
```

output:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "nodes_class_label": [
        {
            "instanceType": "e1.xlarge,
            "nodeType": "cpu",
            "node_name": "hostA"
        },
        {
            "instanceType": "e1.xlarge,
            "nodeType": "cpu",
            "node_name": "hostB"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to pull all the nodes matching any name with wildcard.

```
          label_selectors:
          - "beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=e1.xlarge"
          - "beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=f1.xlarge"
          - "beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=g1.xlarge"
```

expected output:

```
list all e1 label nodes output
list all f1 label nodes output
list all g1 label nodes output
```

my attempted solution:

```
  - name: "Fetch all CPU nodes from clusters using K8s beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type"
    k8s_facts:
      kind: Node
      label_selectors:
      - "beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=*.xlarge"

      verify_ssl: no
    register: cpu_class_list
    failed_when: cpu_class_list == ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible. It is a limitation based on the implementation of the Kubernetes API, unrelated to Ansible or the k8s_facts module.

There are a couple of workarounds, but ultimately I think using a set-based selector is your best option. This would look similar to:

```
- k8s_facts:
    kind: Node
    label_selectors:
      - "beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type in (e1.xlarge, f1.xlarge, g1.xlarge)"
```

You should also be able to pull the instance types out into a variable for code readability and maintenance purposes.

The other option is to just loop over the `k8s_facts` task for each instance type, which I'm guessing you have already considered: `"beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type={{ item }}"`.

Finally, one of your examples in the question will **not** work:

```
label_selectors:
  - "beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=e1.xlarge"
  - "beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=f1.xlarge"
  - "beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=g1.xlarge"
```

This is looking for nodes that meet **all** of those criteria (i.e. `e1.xlarge && f1.xlarge && g1.xlarge`), which will always be none.